# OSM: how to download one layer for a given area ? (water, lakes)

Tags: dictionary, gis, openstreetmap, qgis

I'am doing a GIS map, all is ready, but I still need rivers and lakes.

**1. Where to find the list of all layers existing on OSM ?**

**2. how/where to download one layer for a given area ?** (water, lakes / for a country)

Answer (score 3):

[OSM's primary data format](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) has no equivalent of the GIS concept of "layers". Instead, everything is together, and "tags" are used to identify different features.

You can download [country-by-country OSM downloads from Geofabrik](http://download.geofabrik.de/).

Then you might consider:

- Use [osmosis](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis) to filter the XML data, eg filter to objects having tags `water=*`
- Alternatively, take an OSM data dump and use [osm2pgsql](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) to convert the data into a postGIS database that I think involves layers.